# Select rows from MySQL table where PHP timestamp is older than X

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a user table, where users need to be approved, i want to show users who are not approved and is registered more than 7 days ago.

My user_regdate is a timestamp created with php time() function.

This is what i try, it does not works:

```
mysql_query("select * from users WHERE user_regdate < now() - interval 7 day AND approved='0' order by id;");
```

Thanks

Comment: What does `SELECT now() - interval 7 day` return?

Comment: It returns all rows with approved = 0

Comment: No no, just run that SELECT query that I added as a comment...to return the time value.  What value does it show?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

PHP's timstamps are a simple integer, whereas MySQL's `now()` returns a datetime value. Most likely this will fix up the query:

```
SELECT ... WHERE user_regdate < unix_timestamp(now() - interval 7 day)) ...
```

Basically, without the unix_timstamp() call, you're comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3):

Primitive solution at best, but im not the best at MySQL time calculation

```
$timestamp = strtotime("-7 days");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_regdate < $timestamp AND approved = 0 ORDER BY id");
```

Answer (score 1):

php's time() function outputs a unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970). MySQL's now() function outputs a formatted date (like 2011-6-9 12:45:34)... so I don't think you can compare them like that.

Try using the unix timestamp, minus 7 days, instead of now() in your query:

```
 $7_days_ago = time() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
 mysql_query("select * from users WHERE user_regdate <" . $7_days_ago . " AND approved='0' order by id;");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
select * 
from users 
WHERE DATE_SUB(user_regdate,INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
AND approved='0' 
order by id;
```

Comment: Note that this query will force MySQL to do a full table scan and consequently have significant performance implications.  See Marc's answer for a more index-friendly query.