# Get row with latest date for each unique id after certain date

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

How can I make this query work? I have a table with id, owner_id, date, status

I want to select each unique owner_id that has a date greater than a certain time and only get the row with the latest date.

```
SELECT owner_id, MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date > 1483387036 GROUP BY owner_id
```

I can't seem to get it to work properly.

I edited the question. Sorry I explained it badly. This is not getting the latest date for each owner_id when I run the query. The query above is just an example and the `date` field uses a UNIX timestamp format.

Comment: Use different format of date and also enclose it in quotes: `SELECT owner_id, MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date > '2016-01-12' GROUP BY owner_id` (and also enclose date column name in backticks, as it is mysql reserved keyword).

Comment: `WHERE date > 12-1-2016` well if that's your actual code, you need to quote it. Or, is that pseudo code?

Comment: *"and also enclose date column name in backticks, as it is mysql reserved keyword)"* - @JiriHrazdil `date` is a "keyword" not a "reserved keyword"; two different animals here. See for yourself https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html there's no `(R)` next to it.

Comment: edited my question.. It;s just pseudo code, Sorry for the terrible explanation.

Comment: now someone went and posted an answer based on your original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41432504/1 - two actually. Edit: one was deleted.

Comment: what's `123456789` supposed to represent? unix time?

Comment: yes, unix timestamp

Comment: try to put your date between two quotation like '12-1-2016'

Comment: you really should post an actual unix time stamp example.

Comment: Are u using timestamp or actual date format.

Comment: @ClintC. Unix timestamps always baffle me *lol* but you can have a look at a few of these Q&A's http://stackoverflow.com/q/7099904/1415724 --- http://stackoverflow.com/q/6298882/1415724 they might give you an idea. I always use MySQL's built-in date/datetime functions/types, I've never used Unix timestamps.